# Mediaplayer for WordPress does not play Video in Safari

Tags: wordpress, safari

I did the search, but could not find an answer that helped with my issue. Excuse me if there was one that I overlooked.

I do have the follogin issue: I installed js.mediaplayer for WordPress, and the videos are playing fine on Firefox and Safari on iPad.

However, if I try to play the Video in Safari, it loads and loads and loads, but the video is not playing.

The Theme I am using is "Karma", just in case this is helpful, and the video is included in a video frame.

This is the shortcode used:

```
[video src="http://mydomain.de/img/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" mp4="http://mydomain.de/img/myvideo.mp4" preload="true" autoplay="false" + width="572" + height="311" controlbar="bottom"]
```

In the source-code, it looks like this:

```
<div class="video-wrap video_right"><div class="video-main">
    <div class="video-frame">
    <video id="wp_mep_1" controls="controls" type="video/mp4" src="http://mydomain.de
 /img/myvideo.mp4" width="572" height="311" preload="true" autoplay="false" class="mejs-player"   

data-mejsoptions='{"features":
 ["playpause","current","progress","duration","volume","tracks","fullscreen"]}'>

        <source src="http://mydomain.de/img/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <object width="572" height="311" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
 data="http://mydomain.de/wp-content/plugins/media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player  
/mediaelement
 /flashmediaelement.swf">
            <param name="movie" value="http://wp.vorsorgeconcept.de/wp-content/plugins
 /media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player/mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf" />
            <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&amp;file=http://mydomain.de
 /img/myvideo.mp4" />           
        </object>       
    </video> 
 </div><!-- end video-frame -->
 </div><!-- end video-main -->
```

I thought it might have been a conflict with Jetpack, but nothing changed after disabling the Jetpack Plugin.

Any other idea?

Comment: video is not playing on Windows Safari, right?

Answer (score 2):

If video is not playing on windows Safari then I think Quicktime is the issue. It appears that Safari has a requirement for Quicktime to be installed in order to support HTML5 media.

Install [Quicktime](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/) will fix the safari Video/Audio issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after doing some research the easiest way I could find is to add `poster` argument in the code like this

```
[video width="427" height="240" poster="http://example.com/example.png" mp4="http://example.com/example.mp4"][/video]
```

Here you can see `poster="http://example.com/example.png"` example.png is the image I want to show as still image in the video